# How to make view under view clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the recycler view scroll over the top of the toolbar but the toolbar items (eg. home button) are not clickable.

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <include
        android:id="@id/toolbar_feed"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_feed"/>
    // Inside viewPager is recycler view which scroll over the toolbar
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom_layout"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My only problem is that toolbar home button is not clickable because it is behind viewPager layer. It can work with playing translationZ but it only support API21+. So, you guys have an idea to make this work?

Comment: Did you try  android:clickable="true"?

Comment: @okset Yes, it did not work.

Comment: Can you post the whole xml layout?

Answer (score -1):

Change the order in which you add the views in their parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include
        android:id="@id/toolbar_feed"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_feed"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom_layout"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's not solution for my use case. I need to recycler which be scrolling over the toolbar. In your example, clicks intercepting will be okay but toolbar will be over my recycler view.

Comment: You mentioned about a RecyclerView but I don't see it anywhere to your layout. Without posting all the related to your problem xml files it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: Sorry, before edit question there was a comment where I explain that in viewpager is recycler view.

Comment: So to sum up, you want the RecyclerView to be on top of the toolbar but at the same time you want the click events to be consumed by the toolbar buttons and not by the RecyclerView items. Should the latter ones be clickable or not?

Comment: I want the toolbar and recycler view items to be clickable at the same time, but recycler must be above toolbar. I have made some workaround by making transparent view and placing it above viewpager where the home button is.

Comment: And what are the criteria to decide which view of the two will consume the event when it occurs? I really have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Maybe a screenshot will help.